# next-auth with nextjs secure api routes with middleware

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I want to use `NextAuth` to secure my api routes in NextJS. If user is not authorized, I want to return 401 unauthorized response, but by default `NextAuth` redirect all unauthorized routes (both pages and api) to /sign-in. How I can modify middleware to respond with `NextResponse.json({status:401});`
Right now I have middleware:

```js
export default function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse, event: NextFetchEvent) {

  const notAuthorizedRedirectTo = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/api') ? '/api/unauthorized' : '/sign-in';

  const withAuthResult = withAuth(function (request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
    //if authorized (token provided)
    // console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname);
    // const redirectTO = request.nextUrl.clone();
    // redirectTO.pathname = '/';
    // return NextResponse.redirect(redirectTO);
  }, {
    pages: {
      signIn: notAuthorizedRedirectTo
    }
  })
  return withAuthResult(req as NextRequestWithAuth, event);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/api/protected',
    '/posts/create'
  ]
}
```

And `/api/unauthorized` route:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 401 });
}
```

Is there better way to do it?